# Custom Listbox design

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I have a list of dates that I want to present. Initially I thought of using datepicker but it doesn't have max days or max months (Unbelievable) and this is a requirement for me.
Hence I thought of generating my own dates and presenting it to the user.
Below is how I want to display it
 [image]

I am currently using listbox. I tried combobox, grid view but I am facing the same problem in all of them

**Problem**

When the date is under the two blue lines I want to set it as selected. The only way I can think of is using code by getting position of the line and then get position of each item in listbox to determine which is falling in the range.

1. Is there a xaml way to do this?
2. Any other logic besides determining position? I find this logic extremely crude. A good one would be having a collision box or something which is represented by those lines and when an item hits it, it gets selected

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after mucking around for like 3 days I found following solution to be useful

1. First find the midpoint that is located between the two line. (Find horizontal midpoint, then find   vertical midpoint). I found the midpoint using the following code

   ```
    private void DetermineSelectionLineBoundaries()
    {
     if (SelectionBoundaryUpper == null || HorizontalScrollPanel == null)
     {
      return;
     }

       var transform = SelectionBoundaryUpper.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
       _upperStart = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
       _upperEnd = new Point(_upperStart.X + 100, _upperStart.Y);

       var lowertransform = SelectionBoundaryLower.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
       _lowerStart = lowertransform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

       var midPointHorizontal = CalculateMidpoint(_upperStart, _upperEnd);
       var midPointVertical = CalculateMidpoint(_lowerStart, _upperStart);
       _midPoint = new Point(midPointHorizontal.X, midPointVertical.Y);
   }
   ```
2. Once you have that, on every scroll call

   ```
   VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(_midPoint, Window.Current.Content).ToList();
   ```

   This function will give you all the elements at the point. To be honest I dont just get that element I basically get everything on page that falls vertically on same place as the point. Maybe I am doing something wrong. But the good news is I get only one listbox item. So easy to loop through.

Once that is done, just turn on the IsSelected flag.

Hope this helps someone

I could not find any xaml way to do this.